# How do I replace NA's in dataframe rows where rows is not all NA's

Tags: r

I have dataframe that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(c(1,351,NA,1,0,2,585,0,1,1,3,321,NA,0,1,4,964,NA,NA,NA,5,556,0,1,NA), ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE))
colnames(df) <- c('id','value','v1','v2','v3')
```

Now I want to replace all NA's in the subset `c('v1', 'v2', 'v3')` with 0 (zero) for all rows that are not all NA's.

So I want this:

```
R> df
  id value v1 v2 v3
1  1   351 NA  1  0
2  2   585  0  1  1
3  3   321 NA  0  1
4  4   964 NA NA NA
5  5   556  0  1 NA
```

to end up like this:

```
R> df
  id value v1 v2 v3
1  1   351  0  1  0
2  2   585  0  1  1
3  3   321  0  0  1
4  4   964 NA NA NA
5  5   556  0  1  0
```

Note that `df[4, ]` still have NA's for `c('v1', 'v2', 'v3')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R , here is one way

```
#columns to check for NA
cols <- c("v1", "v2", "v3")
#rows which needs to be replaced
rows <- which(rowSums(is.na(df[cols])) != length(cols))
#Replace values which are NA to 0
df[rows, cols] <- replace(df[rows, cols], is.na(df[rows, cols]), 0)
df
#  id value v1 v2 v3
#1  1   351  0  1  0
#2  2   585  0  1  1
#3  3   321  0  0  1
#4  4   964 NA NA NA
#5  5   556  0  1  0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with good old loop:

```
for (r in 1:nrow(df))
{
  # check that not the all row is na but that there are some na
  if(!all(is.na(df[r,3:5])) && sum(is.na(df[r,3:5]>0)))
  {
    df[r,which(is.na(df[r,3:5]))+2]=0
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`, you can try:

```
cols <- c("v1", "v2", "v3")

df %>%
 mutate(row_na = rowSums(is.na(select(., one_of(cols)))) == length(cols)) %>%
 mutate_at(vars(one_of(cols)), ~ ifelse(!row_na, replace(., is.na(.), 0), .)) %>%
 select(-row_na)

  id value v1 v2 v3
1  1   351  0  1  0
2  2   585  0  1  1
3  3   321  0  0  1
4  4   964 NA NA NA
5  5   556  0  1  0
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `dplyr` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(v1:v3), ~ifelse(is.na(v1) & is.na(v2) & is.na(v3), NA, replace_na(., 0)))
```

Comment: How is it replacing the NAs with zeros?

Comment: oops, typo. Edited!

Answer (score 0):

As simple as possible:

```
df[ !(is.na(df$v1) & is.na(df$v2) & is.na(df$v3)) & is.na(df) ] <- 0
```